# Best tool to cut existing tile sidesplash to fit new range hood

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile, cutting, hood

Our new range hood doesn't sit square or flush with the wall because the new hood sits over some of the original tile (*outlined in red*).

I plan to trace around the hood and remove a 5-inch wide by 1.75 inch tile rectangle.

Red line shows where cut is needed.
I can remove the hood when I make the cut.

Would an oscillating multi tool, dremel, or something else work best, and what type of blade is needed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this is probably dreaming, but do you have any more of the original tiles? If not, I'd go to an angle grinder with a diamond blade, and a dremel with a diamond blade for the corners of the vertical front cut. Cutting tile inside will be extremely dusty.

Comment: Diamond blade, and "what have you got?" - I personally default to an angle grinder, because that's what I have, and have a diamond blade for, but other folks have suggested oscillating saws/tools as an option in other questions. In any case, have an assistant hold a shop vacuum (equipped with a good filter) hose next to it to catch most of the dust, and cover or remove all the food so as not to get the dust that misses the vacuum hose on it.

Comment: mount it in front of the tiles.